# Can Subclass use a delegate method of superclass Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextviewdelegate

Is it possible to use a delegate of superclass on subclass

Example: Class A is superclass of class B and superclass A  uses the text view method example textviewDidChange. can I somehow call [super textViewDidChange] of superclass A on Subclass B even it isn't on header file of class A
if i rediclare the method on subclass B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you specify `UITextViewDelegate`, you're telling the compiler that your `class` meets the specifications for a `UITextViewDelegate`.  If `class A` has all the requirements for a `UITextViewDelegate`, and `class B` is a subclass, then it too will have all the requirements.  Nothing will stop you from assigning any `instance` as a `delegate`, so you still have to be careful with that.

Comment: Also make sure you specify the class that is implementing the delegate methods like you would for the superclass

Comment: im not sure if i understand the part assigning any instance s delegate and G_Money;s sentence specify the class implementing the delegate

sorry english not my first im sure u explained it well but my languange knowlege needs to be more specific 
so u both are saying if i have textfieldDidChange again in subclass it automatically gets all from A and extra things u put on B ?

Comment: In other words, there's no checking that the instance you said was a delegate has actually implemented all the required methods. When you assign the delegate as `myTextView.delegate = theSubclass` the compiler assumes you know what you're doing and that `theSubclass` actually meets the delegate specs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you can. Since class A confirms <UITextViewDelegate> protocol there is no need to redeclare them in header file. Just make sure it implements needed methods.